# Listing users in weblogic domain using WLST 12.1.3

Tags: weblogic12c

Hi I am trying to list users to  weblogic 12.1.3 domain using the WLST and .py file.

```
from weblogic.management.security.authentication import UserReaderMBean
from weblogic.management.security.authentication import GroupReaderMBean
connect('wb_user','wl_passwd','t3://10.xxx.xx.xx:14020')
atns = cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm().getAuthenticationProviders()
for i in atns:
if isinstance(i,UserReaderMBean):
userReader = i
cursor = i.listUsers("*",0)
#print 'Users in realm '+realm.getName()+' are: '
while userReader.haveCurrent(cursor):
  print userReader.getCurrentName(cursor)
  userReader.advance(cursor)
userReader.close(cursor)
```

I am getting the following error. Please help in resolving it:

```
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File ".../userlist/userList.py", line 20, in ?
        at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:623)
        at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:435)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.getAuthenticationProviders(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.jps.wls.providers.trust.TrustServiceIdentityAsserterMBean
```

Comment: Are you using a `wlst.sh` or `.cmd` file that comes with weblogic or a custom one? This kind of error should be really easy to resolve but we need to know your classpath

Comment: Hi its wlst.sh , I am sourcing the setDomainEnv.sh as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting . ./setDomainEnv.sh and the running java weblogic.WLST userList.py , we can just run $WEBLOGIC_HOME/oracle_common/common/wlst.sh userList.py.